# Time it takes to render DOM elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angular

is there a way to detect the amount of time it takes to render DOM elements in the browser?

I'm making an application that purposely does a fair amount of DOM manipulation to test the speed of angular 1 vs angular 2.

However I am having trouble finding information on how to calculate the time it takes to update the DOM elements.

Comment: Chrome Developer Tools Timeline panel?

Comment: _" the time it takes to update the DOM elements"_ is not the same as _"Time it takes to render DOM elements". Except if by "update DOM" you mean "update screen". So which one do you want to measure?

Comment: Deleting my answer since OP doesn't understand how SO works.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`Navigation Timing API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API), for example

```
console.log(
  performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd -
  performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventStart
);
```

Answer (score -1):

What about Firebug? The Net tab will give you timings for loading